# How to check for value in an array without iteration

Tags: ruby

I want a single line of ruby (not using `each`) that will answer this question: Is there a `follower_id` of `2397558816` in this array?

```
myArray = [ #<Follower id: 1, username: "Prep Bootstrap", imageurl: "http://pbs.twimg.com//profile_images/2825468445/2a4...", user_id: "thefonso", follower_id: "2397558816", created_at: "2014-05-21 15:29:03", updated_at: "2014-05-21 15:29:03">, #<Follower id: 2, username: "JAVA Developer", imageurl: "http://pbs.twimg.com//profile_images/2825468445/2a4...", user_id: "thefonso", follower_id: "2352382640", created_at: "2014-05-21 15:29:05", updated_at: "2014-05-21 15:29:05"> ]
```

I am convinced that there must be a ruby method or combo of such that can do this. Can this be done?

Comment: Looks like I may have an answer in .any?...http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F

Comment: It looks like ActiveRecord association. Is it correct?

Comment: You can't do it without iteration, as long as what you have is an array. You can avoid `each`, but using `any?`, `select`, `find` as in some answers below all uses iteration. If the object is a hash, it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: This answer is based on assumption it is an ActiveRecord relation. If it is not, please comment and I'll remove this answer.

This is not a simple array, it is `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, which is a wrapper around an array. You should almost never use pure array objects on it, as this class is responsible for fetching objects from database. Using `any?` will fetch all the records from db and then iterate over it searching for match. Instead you should check it on a db lavel to limit number of fetched records (performance):

```
 relation.exists?(follower_id: 2397558816)
```

Comment: you "see" what I'm trying to do actually. Let me check this out.

Comment: Thanks to all of you, while the other answers work as well, the one given by BroiSatse follows my "intention". Thank you B.

Comment: thefonso, are you quite certain that "the other answers work as well"?

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right way: use [`Enumerable#any?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F):

```
myarray.any? { |v| v.follower_id == 2397558816 }
```

Comment: Are you assuming that the (two) elements of `MyArray` are instances of the class `Follower`?  If they were, wouldn't `MyArray` look like: `=> [#<Follower:0x00000101944b50 @id=1,...`?  Also, if the elements were instances, you wouldn't know if the instance variables had accessors, so I'd think you'd need `instance_variable_get`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(myArray.select {|elem| elem.instance_variable_get(:@id) == 1234567}) != []
```

Returns true if the array contains an element with the given id, and false if not

Comment: My comment on @mdesantis' answer applies equally here.